# Ruby on Rails webpacker asset_pack_path throws undefined method asset_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app that is using Webpacker. I get a strange undefined method error when using `asset_pack_path` - a `NoMethodError` is thrown and says `undefined method 'asset_path' Did you mean? asset_pack_path`. This is a similarly named method but not the one I am calling; `asset_path` does not appear in the app's codebase either.

I believe to be calling the correct path inside of `asset_pack_path` but that does not seem to be consistent with the error. Perhaps there is a versioning mis-match somewhere? I am at a loss with this one. Any ideas or suggestions to resolve this `undefined method` error and use `asset_pack_path` would be helpful.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that `asset_path` was called inside the `asset_pack_path` method - both `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper` `Webpacker::Helper` need to be included for asset_pack_path to work

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call Rails Views helper method inside a Controller.

Try: `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_pack_path`

Comment: No idea why, but I needed `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_pack_path("media/images/logo.png")` - it refused to work for me without the media/images/ part, even though logo.png was inside images/, not in any special place. I figured out what it wanted by running `bin/webpack` in the terminal and looking at the output. Hope it helps someone.